# How to change the height of the view inside the adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the height of the view and decrease height all the bottom view. This works well in the fragment, but does not work in the adapter.
I do not want to squeeze the main view, I need to increase only the size of containerAvatar.

```
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.open_order_item, parent, false);

    containerAvatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container_avatar_size);
    imgAvatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_open_order_avatar);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://neuronovosti.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Drosophila-Brain-1024x1024.jpg")
            .into(imgAvatar);

    containerAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = containerAvatar.getLayoutParams();
            final ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(containerAvatar);
            a.setDuration(500);
            a.setParams(lp.height, lp.height * 2);
            containerAvatar.startAnimation(a);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    private int startHeight;
    private int deltaHeight; // distance between start and end height
    private View view;

public ResizeAnimation(View v) {
    this.view = v;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

    view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (startHeight + deltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
    view.requestLayout();
}

public void setParams(int start, int end) {

    this.startHeight = start;
    deltaHeight = end - startHeight;
}

@Override
public void setDuration(long durationMillis) {
    super.setDuration(durationMillis);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
```

[image]

That's what you need
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using "holder"?

Comment: @GeylaniARCA, no, I do not need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with `setLayoutParams()` Method of `View`** -

```
private void setDimensions(View view, int width, int height){
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**Added it on your Adapter -**

```
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.open_order_item, parent, false);

    containerAvatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container_avatar_size);
    imgAvatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_open_order_avatar);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://neuronovosti.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Drosophila-Brain-1024x1024.jpg")
            .into(imgAvatar);

    containerAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setDimensions(containerAvatar, 100, 100);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void setDimensions(View view, int width, int height){
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}

}
```